# How to get variable from editText factory pattern

Tags: android

I am trying to write a program that works out areas of shapes, using Factory pattern.

I have tried to use the debugger but I am really new to programming so not to clued up. I have no error message or red lines. 
MainActivity:

```
package com.example.shape;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ShapeFactory myShapeFactory;
    Shape myShape;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myShapeFactory = new ShapeFactory();
    }


    public void convert(View view) {
        //This tell it to collect the height variable from user input
        EditText heightEditText = findViewById(R.id.heightEditText);
        String getHeight = heightEditText.getText().toString();
        myShape.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(getHeight));


        //This tell it to collect the height variable from user input pass as String, then accept into shape as double for width variable
        EditText widthEditText =  findViewById(R.id.widthEditText);
        String getWidth = widthEditText.getText().toString();
        myShape.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(getWidth));

        //This tell is to allow the user to choose if the area is for a triangle or square
        EditText shapeTypeEditText = findViewById(R.id.shapeTypeEditText);
        String ShapeType = shapeTypeEditText.getText().toString();


        //This states if T is entered to display the area of a Triangle
        myShape = myShapeFactory.getShape("T");
        Toast.makeText(this, Double.toString(myShape.Area()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //This states if S is entered to display the area of a Square
        myShape = myShapeFactory.getShape("S");
        Toast.makeText(this, Double.toString(myShape.Area()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Class Shape:

```
  package com.example.shape;

public abstract class Shape {
    //set variable types to double
    private double width;
    private double height;


        //tells it to get the variable width from input
        public double getWidth () {
        return width;
        }
        //tells it to set the variable width from input
        public void setWidth ( double _width) {
            width = _width;
        }

        public double getHeight () {
        return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(double _height){
            height = _height;
        }

        public abstract double Area();
    }
```

---

```
package com.example.shape;

public class ShapeFactory {
        public Shape getShape(String ShapeType) {
            if (ShapeType==null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (ShapeType=="T") {
                return new Triangle();
            }
            if (ShapeType=="S") {
                return new Square();
            }
            return null;

        }
}


----------
    package com.example.shape;

    public class Square extends Shape {
        @Override
        public double getArea() {
            return super.getHeight() * super.getWidth();
        }

            public double getTinsOfPaint() {
                return super.getHeight()*super.getWidth()/24;
        }
    }


    ----------
    package com.example.shape;

    public class Triangle extends Shape {
        @Override
        public double getArea() {
            return super.getHeight()*super.getWidth()/2;
        }


        public double getTinsOfPaint() {
            return super.getHeight()*super.getWidth()/2/24;
        }

    }
```

The user should be able to enter in the width and height and these be passed to a super class Shape, which has sub classes of triangle and Square that will work out the areas then display it in a toast.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing please paste the logs

Comment: You are overwriting your ```myShape``` object with a new shape  ```myShape = myShapeFactory.getShape("T")```.  How the new shape will calculate the area based on the input if you don't set it up?

Comment: 'package com.example.shape` does not come in the middle of the class, you have two packages in the same file.

Comment: You created a method in your main activity (convert) but you're not calling it anywhere.

Comment: @AkhilaMadari I'm sure that's just the editing here. I submitted a new edit to separate the two files.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo what is your exact error?

Comment: @AkhilaMadari I'm not the OP, tag Noob instead

Comment: overwriting is fine, as you are toasting, but show your factory method and your square and triangle class

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are having is that you are overwriting the myShape object, which you already setup with values, with a new Shape object which doesn't have the values setup.

There are a few ways to solve this issue. Here are some examples:

You could setup the widht, height, and other values so it can calculate the Area correctly:

```
  myShape = myShapeFactory.getShape("T");
  myShape.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(getWidth)); // You need to setup the width, etc.
  Toast.makeText(this, Double.toString(myShape.Area()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You could modify your factory to accept a parent shape so it can inherit all the values (width, height, etc).

```
  myShape = myShapeFactory.getShape("T", myShape);
  Toast.makeText(this, Double.toString(myShape.Area()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

For this, I would advice to read about Clonable interface and the clone method.
Also, you could check about serialization and copy constructors.

You could add a method to your Shape so it can inherit the values of another shape:

```
  myNewShape = myShapeFactory.getShape("T");
  myNewShape.inheritProperties(myShape);
  Toast.makeText(this, Double.toString(myNewShape.Area()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This inheritProperties method would just copy the properties of myShape into your myNewShape.

Let me know if this does make sense to you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will give it a try and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: I had a go at what you suggested but it still did not work. However, I am unsure whether I did it correctly. I have posted all the other classes as requested in one of the responses, any help would be greatly appreciated.